# Force break line inside flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.cnt {
  display: flex;
  margin: 50px;
  background: #ffff00;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.cnt div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #999;
  margin: 10px;
}

.cnt::after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
}

.flex-item:nth-child(6) {
  order: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="cnt">
  <div class="flex-item one"></div>
  <div class="flex-item two"></div>
  <div class="flex-item three"></div>
  <div class="flex-item four"></div>
  <div class="flex-item five"></div>
  <div class="flex-item six"></div>
</div>
```

The problem I have is that I can break line only on the last item... How am I actually able to brake line whenever I want it to? For example, if I want to break line after class `.two`, how can I do it?

**EDIT**

I'm an idiot. This **is** actually how you do it. You just need to pass the items you want to be in the next `order`. Obviously you may do this only once.

So, to break line in the second box, you need to pass the `.three`, `.four`, `.five` and `.six` to `order: 1`. See here: https://jsfiddle.net/r33muub3/4/ 
I changed the `justify-content` to `left` so it will be much more obvious

Comment: @Fran thanks, I forgot to add the link to jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/r33muub3/

Answer (score 0):

After some extensive research, I have found that not only was my first response incorrect, but the method of adding a newline in the `content:` property is not what I indicated. I apologize.

The proper way to add a newline (as I found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17048164/7712624) to a similar question) is to use not `<br>` but `\A` in the `content:` property, and additionally to format the style of the element created by `::after` (or `::before`) in the following fashion:

```
.two::after {
  content: "\A";
  white-space: pre;
}
```

While this bit of code does accomplish inserting a newline in the "anonymous element" created by assigning a `content:` property to an `::after`-selected element, It does not solve this issue of dealing with `<div>` elements in a flex layout.

Again, many apologies for my previous incorrect answer. I have retained my previous answer in order to explain **why** it was wrong and to give more context to this answer.

---

#### Additional Resources:

- Another answer to a similar quation that may help answer this one: [Line break in multi-line flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29733127/7712624).
- Another similar question regarding line breaks in flexboxes: [Text not breaking inside of flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36154678/text-not-breaking-inside-of-flexbox).

---

## My previous answer was incorrect:

***Why:*** *The* `.class::after {content: "";}` *statement does not place items after the selected element. Rather, it places its argument inside an anonymous element which is then appended to the existing contents of the selected element. See [this site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after) for a description of the* `::after` *tag, and [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content) for information about the actual behavior of the* `content:` *property.*

You can add a style:

```
div.two::after {content: "<br />";}
```

This will add a line break after every `<div>` element with `class="two"`. The `::after` selector will apply the style directly at the end of any matching element's contents. In this case, we add some text, a line break (`<br />`) to that space after a `<div class="two">` using the `content:`  CSS property. Note the quotes around the line break `"<br />"`; these ensure the argument is processed as a string.

Comment: any working example? 0_o

Comment: Sorry, I incorrectly formatted my answer, it should be correct now.

Comment: feel free to use my jsfiddle link to show me how would you implement it  https://jsfiddle.net/r33muub3/   don't forget to click "update" and show me it :)

Comment: I'm suspecting flexbox is thwarting this approach, instead dumping the  content into the div element itself. I am researching this now.

Comment: Yeah, I know pal... that's why I was so curious about it :D  I think I got this now... I'm just an idiot. will post an update

Comment: Hey! don't downvote him! at least he tried to help. I upvoted you buddy!

Comment: Answer should be fixed now. Hope this helps!

Comment: no line-break with this method. Using chrome.